# Differentiate between ruby and sidekiq in New Relic

Tags: newrelic

in the process inspector I see `ruby (ubuntu)` while I'm using rainbows! and sidekiq, basically new relic aggregates all the data under ruby, I'd like to distinguish between the two.

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

New Relic should automatically detect and differentiate Sidekiq jobs from your other dispatchers if you're using one of the later Ruby agent versions (see https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/ruby/sidekiq-instrumentation and https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/ruby).

You could also assign Sidekiq processes to a different app_name in New Relic, so that you'll have separate dashboards. You can configure this either by prepending your Sidekiq startup command with `NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME="Background-jobs"` or by configuring this in the "environments" section towards the end of your newrelic.yml:

```
background:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: true
  app_name: 'Background-jobs'
```

(source: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/ruby/monitoring-ruby-background-processes-and-daemons#config_file)

Then, just make sure to restart your application so that the new config options can register.

Comment: I'm afraid but setting the new key in the yml file did not solve the problem. Under Servers => Processes I always see an aggregate under `ruby`, and it includes both my Rails app and Sidekiq, they do share the same codebase. I'm not sure where else to look. My processes after the switch to puma: http://pastie.org/pastes/8513477/text?key=yi7aisjvtgpcgi4gdprixg